# Textbox in SharePoint lists

Tags: 2007, inputformtextbox

Is it possible to insert a textbox in a SharePoint list?
For example, if I want to collect my customers'feedback, a Textbox directly in the column "Feedback" would be great, avoiding them to edit each items to write their feedback.

But how this "data" could be stored in the list?

This customisation would be an "user-friendly" option greatly appreciated by the customers/users.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box feature for this. You can create a custom webpart or Custom page where you can show the listitem in a simple Grid and provide a textbox for the Feedback. And on Update link of the row you can update that lisitem programmatically.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer, but I expected more informations/explanations, though.
"There is no out of the box feature", it seems it's a recurrent answer when asking about SharePoint...

Comment: Hmm.. Let me know what other information\explanation you require. As to acheive some functionality that is not provided by Sharepoint we require to customize that sharepoint we want.

Comment: I'm a SharePoint/Web design novice, more steps by steps explanations are welcome, or link to a tutorial.
But I understand the concept, I just don't know how/where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading this incorrectly, but yes you can add a multi line text box in a list. From the list settings you can create a column, give it a name and then select multi line txt - Decide on your other attributes and OK it.

The problem is making it only one customer to access that part of the list.

You may like to think about a Survey where you can ask for directed feed back and then send a link to each customer. (Site Actions - create - Survey (under tracking))

Sorry I don't know the entire situation otherwise I could help more. Remember this is only a forum so answers tend to be of the quick nature.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Magpie13 for the information, but what I'm looking for is a way to fill the column Feedback directly in a textbox (like Excel if you want).